# Not Receiving Multiple Partial View data on Postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Please can you help on the below query.
I have got a main view and partial view. In main view looping through based on the count of model, the partial views will be rendered. The Partial View is as per below

-----------------Partial View----------------------

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("books"))
{
    <div id="bookRow" class="bookRow">
        <div class='container'>
            <div class="align-left">
                <h1>Book Name</h1>
                <h2>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BookName)</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="align-right">
                <h1>Author</h1>
                <h2>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Author)</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="align-right">
                <h1>Publisher</h1>
                <h2>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Publisher)</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="align-right">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.isConfirm)
                @Html.Hidden("Id", @Model.Id)
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="deleteRow">Delete</a>
        </div>
     </div>
}
```

-------------------Main View----------------------

```
@model IEnumerable<TDLProject.Models.BookViewModel>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Books</legend>

    <div id="new-Book">
        @foreach (var model in Model)
        {
            @Html.Partial("_DynamicPartialView", model)
        }
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="button" id="addBook" name="addBook" value="Add Book" />
        <br />
    </div>
    <br />
</fieldset>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Submit" />
    </div>
}
```

-------------Controller--------------

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Contact(IEnumerable<BookViewModel> bookModel)
        {
            // To do: do whatever you want with the data
            return View();
        }
```

The Problem is I am not receiving the data posted from View to the Controller on Click of Submit button. I have multiple partial views of same model on the main view and when click of submit button I need all the partial view data to posted to controller. In Partial View I am using BeginCollectionItem. Please can you help on this.

Comment: Thanks Excellent Stephen. Working Fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A form only posts back the name/value pairs of its successful controls, and your not generating the form controls inside the `<form>` tags.

Change the code to move the `@Html.Partial()` code inside the `<form>` (simplified)

```
@model IEnumerable<TDLProject.Models.BookViewModel>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @foreach (var model in Model)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_DynamicPartialView", model)
    }
    <input type="button" id="addBook" name="addBook" value="Add Book" />
    <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Submit" />
}
```

You also need to change the POST method signature to

```
public ActionResult Contact(IEnumerable<BookViewModel> books)
```

to match the name you use in the `@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("books"))` method.

Comment: Hi Stephen, I placed  two kendo drop downs ( cascading ) in partial view as below                                          @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.ServerMakeId)
                                      .Name("servermake"+Model.Id.ToString())
                                      .DataTextField(CommonConstants.Description)
                                      .DataValueField(CommonConstants.Id)
                                      .OptionLabel("Select Server Make")

                                        })) . The Id ServerMakeId is string which is getting null.

Comment: @VVR147493, You need to ask a new question with the relevant details (but in any case you need to remove `.Name("servermake"+Model.Id.ToString()` - NEVER attempt to override the `name` attribute

Comment: Thanks Stephen. When I add a placeholder which is string in a model the data in the dropdown is getting in controller. But when I add a new item in the main and same multiple partial views the dropdown values in partialviews is not getting in controller.

Comment: @VVR147493, I'm not psychic and cannot possibly guess what your doing. You need to ask a new question showing all the relevant details